# What is the meaning of "tu sé"?

Tags: vocabulaire

Reading *Astérix* and came upon a phrase that I couldn't find in a dictionary or google search, pictured below where an offscreen Belgian character looking for beer says "tu sé" as part of a longer dialogue. What does "sé" mean?

[image]

Comment: Sidenote, the Belgian character's dialogue has certain random quirks that are presumably in imitation of a Belgian manner of speaking, but some are genuinely confusing. For instance they also say "nous avions penséi" [sic] at one point?

Comment: Peut-être « tu sais » ?  *ça est pas* is a belgicisme, "penséi" peut-être pour suggérer un e ouvert (en Belgique le [e] devient souvent [ɛ])

Comment: Ah alors peut-être ce n'est qu'un cas de faire semblant d'être belge, le son de leur paroles?

Comment: C'est ce que je pense, mais ce n'est qu'une opinion, ce qui est sûr et certain c'est qu'il n'y a pas de mot français qui s'écrive *sé*, mais je pense que tu t'en doutais !

Comment: @None *No sé, no sé !... Ils n'ont que ces mots là à la bouche, ces bougres de Canaques de tonnerre de Brest !...* :-)

Comment: @temporary_user_name Are you really sure the character is supposed to be Belgian and not North French? Which Astérix is this from?

Comment: Vol. 10, *Astérix legionnaire.* And yeah, the character specifically states on page 18 that he's Belgian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is a (purposefully) wrong writing of "tu sais" (you know).

The humour in *Astérix* relies, among other things, on (usually nice) caricatures of regional habits. Belgians are pictured as fond of "cervoise" (which is equivalent to beer), and speaking in a way that resembles the accent and expressions of francophone Belgians of the modern times.

Indeed, Belgians, as well as people who live in the north of France, tend to pronounce "tu sais" as "tu sé" (as in "café") (while others pronounce it "tu sè" as the english word "say").

By the way, "ça est pas" in the beginning of the sentence is also not something you would hear in France. French would say "c'est pas" (casual) or "ça n'est pas" (formal).

Comment: The English word *say* sounds much more like *sé* than *sais* to my (admittedly Anglophone) ears. Note that *say* and *says* have different vowels in English, and *says* is a homophone of the French word *seize*.

Comment: I personally cannot distinguish between the vowel at the end of *café* and the vowel in *say*. If there's a different I struggle to hear it. And this is despite 14 years learning this language lol.

Comment: On second thought, I think what Anne wrote on that point is mistaken - *while others pronounce it "tu sè" as the english word "say"* - I'm reasonably sure this isn't right, because *say* and *café* are using the same vowel. If you meant "while others pronounce it like *è*," then *say* was a misleading choice of phonetic analogy.

Comment: @temporary_user_name: The vowel in *say* is a diphthong,  something like *seille* in French (i.e., rhyming with *veille*), while the vowel in *café,* pronounced properly in French, is a pure vowel. Anglophone ears have a hard time hearing this difference, but I suspect this is one of the telltale signs of an English accent.

Comment: @PeterShor Both [e] and [ɛ] are pure vowels in the terms you used.  It's not just a question of diphthongs.  *Tu sais* is the latter, [ɛ] "le e fermé."  *Tu sé* is the former, /e/ "le e ouvert.".

Comment: @AnneAunyme I'm guessing Flemish/Brusseleir rather than francophone. Diphtong /eɪ/ has been (mis)spelled "é" by the authors. It's quite different from how people from North France pronounce "sais".